# Share weights in coupled gans - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the tensorflow implementation of [CoGAN](https://github.com/andrewliao11/CoGAN-tensorflow). I could change which layers can share the weights and which couldn't, except for the first layer of discriminator. I am not sure of what is going wrong here.

The error part of code is

```
h0 = prelu(self.d_bn0(conv2d(image, self.c_dim, name='d'+branch+'_h0_conv', reuse=share_params), reuse=share_params),
                        name='d'+branch+'_h0_prelu', reuse=share_params)
```

where `'reuse=share_params'` should allow to share weights between the two branches. Should this be dealt in a different manner?

The Traceback looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "main.py", line 41, in main
    dataset_name=FLAGS.dataset, is_crop=FLAGS.is_crop, checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
File "/home/iiitd/Desktop/CoGAN-tensorflow-master/model.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.build_model()
File "/home/iiitd/Desktop/CoGAN-tensorflow-master/model.py", line 101, in build_model
    self.D2_logits, self.D2 = self.discriminator(self.images2, self.y,  share_params=True, reuse=False, name='D2')
File "/home/iiitd/Desktop/CoGAN-tensorflow-master/model.py", line 287, in discriminator
    h0 = prelu(self.d_bn0(conv2d(image, self.c_dim, name='d'+branch+'_h0_conv', reuse=share_params), reuse=share_params),
File "/home/iiitd/Desktop/CoGAN-tensorflow-master/ops.py", line 82, in conv2d
    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1024, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 850, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 346, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 331, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 650, in _get_single_variable
    "VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable d2_h0_conv/w does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. Please format your question to make this easier to read

Comment: To share something you need to create that variable; from the error msg, it seems you haven't created the variable you want to share.

Comment: 'branch' was undefined.Solved as                                                                                        def discriminator(self, image, y=None, share_params=False, reuse=False, name='D'):
        if '1' in name:
            d_bn3 = self.d1_bn3
     d_bn2 = self.d1_bn2
     branch = '1'
        elif '2' in name:
            d_bn3 = self.d2_bn3
            d_bn2 = self.d2_bn2
     branch = '2'
    
        h0 = prelu(self.d1_bn0(conv2d(image, self.c_dim, name='d_h0_conv', reuse=share_params), reuse=share_params),
         name='d_h0_prelu', reuse=share_params)